# Preventing cycle through page elements using TAB

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I have a requester `div` which is over of all my page and I want to prevent access to other elements of page using TAB while the dialog is opened. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI does that by binding to the `keypress` event for modal dialog boxes. When <kbd>TAB</kbd> is pressed, it manually handles the switching of focus between elements within the modal dialog only. The default behaviour is suppressed (`return false`) so focus is not switched to external elements.

Relevant source here: [ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/2f89f356433d83a56135070c2f7d3b188c756b5a/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js#L294)

Answer (score 2):

You can either set each element to be `disabled`, or set their [`tabindex`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.11.1) to zero. Use jQuery to set `$(selector).prop('disabled',true)` or `$(selector).attr('tabindex',0)`.

Comment: isn't there any other method without that huge loop? because there are lot of links and other focusable elements in the page.

Comment: None that I know of. Perhaps the jQuery UI developers have done something different; I don't have time to dive into their code.